# Why my score drooped to 20 from 80 over night? (I didn't do anything)

Tags: wordpress, google-pagespeed

Google Pagespeed: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsuper-zava.co.il%2F

My URL: https://super-zava.co.il/

I talked to my host support (BlueHost) and they told me that the problem is not related to their server. I didn't touch anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it is related to your ISP.

The problem seems to be related with the time that Google's services is taking to fetch the page, so it's either Google's fault or your ISP's, as mentioned above. Google's saying the first request took ~ 5 seconds for them (with the first byte taking around ~0,35 to be received).

The page loads just fine here, perhaps they have changed Google's IP priority.

I reckon it's not because of you or your site.

From me, the latency to your server is around 158 ms, and is taking around 1 second to load the page.

What you can do is to put your site behind a WAF like Cloudflare.

Comment: I didn’t say it was, but they can change priority, or even put in an automated blacklist if they see too many requests from the same ip or range.

Comment: As I said in the post, use Cloudflare and try again in a few hours, it should resolve your problem.

Comment: So the site isn't really slow? Do you think my google ads rank score will be damaged?

Comment: From what I've tested no, your site isn't slow, but it will affect your rank score if they are somehow blocking the entire google ip range, so google will think it's slow, when in fact it is not. This could possibly be resolved with cloudflare

Comment: you're welcome! please let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 0):

as reported past week on pagespeed insights discuss google groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/luQUtDOnoik
it seems that **this is a problem (or a change in programming api) of PageSpeed Insights web itself**

Comment: Here you have you rating with webpagetest https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190204_Z5_188c84571d698d723eb3a384c7fdf55e/

Comment: more information of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504141/google-page-speed-drop-says-i-can-save-more-loading-time-even-though-nothing-c/