# Google Page Speed Drop, says I can save more loading time, even though nothing changed

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, deferred-loading, pagespeed-insights

I'm testing my pagespeed everyday several times. My page often receives a grade between 94 to 98, with the main problems being:

> Eliminate render-blocking resources - Save 0.33
>
> Defer unused CSS - Save 0.15 s

And in Lab data, all values are green.

Since yesterday, suddenly page speed has dropped, to about 80-91 range,
with the problems being:

> Eliminate render-blocking resources - Save ~0.33
>
> Defer unused CSS - Save ~0.60 s

And it is also saying my `First CPU idle` is slow `~4,5ms`

And so is `time to interactive` , `~4.7`

And sometimes `speed index` is slow as well.

It also started to show `Minimize main-thread work` advice, which didn't show earlier.

The thing is, I did not change anything in the page. Still same HTML, CSS and JS. This also not a server issue, I don't have a CPU overuse problem.

On Gtmetrix I'm still getting the same 100% score and same 87% Yslow score, with the page being fully loaded somewhere between 1.1s to 1.7s, making 22 HTTP requests in total size of 259kb, just like before.

On Pingdom I also get the same 91 grade as before, with page load speed around 622ms to 750ms.

Therefore, I can't understand this sudden change in the way Google analyzes my page.
I'm worried of course it will affect my rankings.

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that **this is a problem of PageSpeed Insights web itself** as it is reported now on some pagespeed insights discuss google groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/luQUtDOnoik

The point is that if you try to test your performnce direclty from another lighthouse web test, for example:
**https://www.webpagetest.org/lighthouse**
You will see your previous rates

In our case, in this site we always had 90+ on mobile but now google page rate has been reduced to 65+
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.test-english.com%2F&tab=mobile
but it still remains 90+ in webpagetest.org:   https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190204_2G_db325d7f8c9cddede3262d5b3624e069/

Answer (score 0):

This bug was acknowledged by Google and now has been fixed. Refer to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/by9-TbqdlBM

> From Feb 1 to Feb 4 2019, PSI had a bug that led to lower performance
>   scores. This bug is now resolved.
>
> The headless Chrome infrastructure used by PageSpeed Insights had a
>   bug that reported uncompressed (post-gzip) sizes as if they were the
>   compressed transfer sizes. This led to incorrect calculations of the
>   performance metrics and ultimately a lower score. The mailing list
>   thread titled [[BUG] [compression] Avoid enormous network payloads /
>   Defer unused CSS doesn't consider compression](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/luQUtDOnoik/discussion) covered this issue in
>   greater detail. Thanks for Raul and David for their help.
>
> As of Monday Feb 4, 5pm PST, the bug is completely addressed via a new
>   production rollout.

Comment: does not seem fixed enough to me. it is better, but surely not back to same scores.

Comment: @user8411456 Are both the mobile and desktop scores lower than before? They mentioned that desktop scores would be lower than before because of recalibration introduced in Lighthouse 4.1.0 ( https://github.com/googlechrome/lighthouse/pull/6969)

Comment: actually, desktop barley changed, mobile is lower, opposite from what would be expected